# How to invalid a string line url with regex

Tags: javascript, json, regex, string, url

I want to use regex on my project, and my issue is the following.

My regex is the following `/([a-z_"\/\{\},\[\]]+)\b/g`

Each string is considered valid if it contains only these characters:

- lower case letters
- Any of these: `_/{}[],`

My string

```
[
  "/persons/AA",
  "/personsTest/throw_web_Application",
  "/persons/{id}",
  "/personsSSS",
  "/persons/ping"
]
```

[image: It return me that]

As you can see, it stop when it's "/"

And i want to invalid my entire line when it's doesn't good for my regex.

Thank you :)

Comment: Are you trying to parse JSON using regex?  Why?  Parse the JSON into an array of strings first, then run your regex against each string.

Comment: You are going about this wrong.  What are you trying to do?  Which strings are you intending to match?  We can show you a better way of doing this.

Comment: I use a **spectral validation** app which is use with Json file, and i don't have to change my json file, just my regex and a JSON path to find my lines. And my Json is verify line by line.

Comment: What are the conditions of validation for each line?

Comment: I want to invalid a whole line like `"/personsTest/throw_web_Application"`.

Comment: Why?  What makes that line invalid?  Please describe the conditions that makes each line valid, not just one individual line.  Your question might be closed if you can't be specific enough for us to help.

Comment: Allow : lowercase letters _ / { } [ ] ,

Comment: Is my edit to your question accurate?

Comment: Now yes, sorry for that

Comment: Why did you remove the JSON from the question?  You have changed the question itself.  I'm of a mind to revert it back to what you had before.  Why did you do that?  I've deleted my answer and am moving on.

Comment: Because it is more simple that you think, it's not an array but just a string, I didn't know if you was always here, I just wanted to correct that to clarify more as you said, sorry again

Comment: You had JSON in the question in a string.  You wrote your regex to operate against the entire JSON string at once.  Removing the JSON and pretending you only had a single string completely alters the question.

Comment: My app work like this, line by line or string by string, it was just many example, 
but I agree, it was awkward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This declares a string ***invalid*** if it finds any character that is ***not*** in the acceptable set of characters:

```
[^a-z_\/{}[\],]
```

[See Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/VNmoaL/2/)

```js
let strings = [
  "/persons/AA",
  "/personsTest/throw_web_Application",
  "/persons/{id}",
  "/personsSSS",
  "/persons/ping"
];

for (let string of strings) {
    if (/[^a-z_\/{}[\],]/.test(string)) {
        console.log("Invalid string: ", string);
    }
    else {
        console.log("Valid string: ", string);
    }
}
```